# Does CRC help prevent security attack or guarantee integrity of data?

Tags: security, ssl, tcp, crc

I've seen a c/c++ program which uses CRC to double check received data from TCP socket.
I didn't understand why CRC is used in an application. I believed that CRC is only needed in layer 2 to 4 i.e. link layer or transport layer maybe (network layer also?).

But today, my coworker told me that CRC helps prevent security attacks. He doubted there could be an attacker who changes data packets. This is his reason why CRC is needed in TCP socket program.

But I still cannot 100% agree with him. I think an attacker who is able to change the data packet, I believe he also can manipulate CRC no to be caught.

I think RSA is for this kind of security. It is HTTPS in HTTP and SSL in TCP.
If so - If I am right - CRC is not needed. Instead of CRC encryption algorithm is the one which really needed.

Am I missing something?
Is CRC useful in TCP socket programming?

Comment: TCP already contains a checksum in each packet. This is used to guarantee correct delivery. Where an error occurs, TCP will re-request the packet.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general security, not programming.

Comment: The point of this question is not about security. It is about the necessity of CRC in socket programming. I want to know generally why socket programmers use CRC on TCP data.

Answer (score 2):

> But today, my coworker told me that CRC helps prevent security attacks.

This is sheer nonsense. It prevents nothing. It might possibly aid *detection* of an attack, *after* it has happened. It isn't the same thing.

> He doubted there could be an attacker who changes data packets. This is his reason why CRC is needed in TCP socket program.

If your colleague 'doubted there could be an attacker', it is logically incoherent for him to also propsoe a solution to the attack.

I had a colleague who was keen on verifying TCP/IP streams. In 1992-3. I've never done it since, and I've never seen a corrupted TCP download either. How many times have you had to re-download anything due to data corruption?

Comment: "I've never seen a corrupted TCP download either". Then you are really lucky. I have problems with corrupted files about once per month (and no, i´m not somewhere in the jungle of africa or something like that). (Well "problems"...i check some SHA etc., it fails, then re-download. Not more problems, but still...)

Comment: Never experienced it in over 18 years of Internet downloads.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, CRC and encryption algorithms are quite different.
CRC detects changes (with a bit of luck). There are better ECCs which can even
correct some wrong bytes, but all of them can be "tricked" by humans.

Encryption can be used with or without ECCs, independent of it.
And it prevents usually that an attacker can read the data, at least.

The network layer isn´t important here.
(Because there are errors in every normal network, the underlying layers have some basic
error control, ie. CRC, and they manage to re-send bad data so that you as programmer won´t
need to implement that yourself. But if you need ~100% reliable data, the built-in CRCs are
not sufficient.)

What your coworker says about data can´t be changed is completely nonsense.
And yes, if someone changes it, he will also change any error correction data
(any ECC data which is not inside of a encryted thing (and then it wouldn´t make sense
because of the properties of modern encryption algorithms)).
After all, ECC is only to prevent technical errors.

I wouldn´t agree with a generalization like "RSA is needed".
There are many encryption systems with different properties and purpose.
The question is: What are you trying to prevent with encryption?
If you want to prevent that an attacker can read the data sent to you,
RSA is at least a possible choice.
If you want to prevent that the attacker can sent you his own data,
a public-key-system like RSA wihout anything else won´t help at all.
...

And CRC etc. are still useful, even with encryption.
RSA won´t help you if some bits change during transmission in the network cable
(quite the contrary, it will be worse. Not only few bit will be bad, but whole blocks)
And again: Yes, this happens every day.